# How to solve for the radius of a sphere using iteration?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to help my son prepare for an exam. I am many years out of school. How can I solve the below question, and explain the solution coherently? Any outside references are welcome, such as YouTube videos, etc. I need to relearn this material too if I am to be of any help.

[image]

Comment: So iterating will converge to the cube root of 239. The idea is that this result is being approximated with only the square root operation.

Comment: They just want you to plug in the values. This has nothing to do with spheres (they could have just as well said that $r$ is the number of elephants in Asia). Just plug in $r_1$ to get $r_2$ and then $r_2$ to get $r_3$ and so on, till you get the desired accuracy they ask for.

Comment: If you solve the equation where the r's are replaced with x, you find that when you get to $r_i$ the cube root, the result sets and does not change.

Comment: Is a calculator allowed?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, a calculator is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they want you to do is this:
$$r_1 = 7\\r_2 = \sqrt{\frac{239}7} \approx 5.843\\
r_3 \approx \sqrt{\frac{239}{5.843}} \approx 6.395\\
r_4 \approx \sqrt{\frac{239}{6.395}}\approx 6.113\\
r_5 \approx \sqrt{\frac{239}{6.113}}\approx 6.253\\
r_6 \approx \sqrt{\frac{239}{6.253}}\approx 6.183\\
r_7 \approx \sqrt{\frac{239}{6.183}}\approx 6.218$$

At this point you see that when rounded to one decimal place, the two last iterations are "$6.2$".

The answer to (a) are the values of $r_2$ and $r_3$ above. The answer to (b) is $6.2$.

Note that although I only wrote down the values to $3$ decimal places, I performed the calculations to the full accuracy I could get from the calculator.

Once I had found $r_2$, I hit the $\frac 1x$ key to invert the answer, multiplied by 239, pressed "=", then hit the $\sqrt x$ key to get the value for $r_3$. And similarly for the later values. This both sped up the process, and assured better accuracy of my calculations.

---

The exercise appears to be about nothing more than interpreting an iteration formula and using it to find the iterant values. They don't even tell you what the iteration formula is doing. (Though perhaps they lifted it from someone else's exercise, where $\frac{4\pi}3 239$ was the volume of a sphere, and the purpose was to compute the radius. But in their copy they dropped everything except a pointless introduction of "$r$" as the radius of a sphere.)

In this case, the iterations are converging to the cube root of $239$, but you do not need to know that, much less understand why, to answer the problem. All they are after is the rote calculation of the numbers, and stopping when the first decimal place stops changing.